# How to refer to the datasource directory in MS Visual Studio unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, app-config

I have created an App.config file in the MS Visual Studio. The content of the App.config file is as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyExcelConn" connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=TestCases\data.xlsx;defaultdir=.; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="MyExcelDataSource" connectionString="MyExcelConn" dataTableName="TestData$" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
</configuration>
```

I have created a folder named "TestCases" in the same directory as the App.config file. I put the data.xlsx file inside the TestCases folder. For your information, data.xlsx is the data source of my unit tests. I coded the directory of the data source as TestCases\data.xlsx but it doesn't work. I don't want to hard code it as "C:\User...." as this would require me to change the code if I wish to run the code on another computer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options

1. This is the easiest one. set a `[DeploymentItem("YourExcelFile")]` attribute on your Test class or Test method, that way you can refer to them from your config using a relative path of `.\YourExcelFile`.
2. This one is harder, since MsTest always drops the TestResults folder in the same location (relative to your solution) you can use a `..\..\..\..\Project\YourExcelFile` path to it. But beware, TFS' Team Build may use a different relative path and before you know it you need to do trickery in the build system for this to work.
3. Copy the Excel file to a wellknown location, like `c:\TestSources\MyDataSource` and map the file to that location using your TFVC Source Control workspace setup. This will allow your test configuration to point to the full path, which it should always be able to find.